# Filter Arrays in Angular/Formly

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-formly

I have an array of fields using formly, I want to filter the array to just include items with specific keys.

```typescript
const questionSet = [
  createInput('hi','hi'),
  createInput('hey','hey'),
  createInput('hello','hello'),
  ];
const finalSet = questionSet.filter(q => ['hi', 'hey'].some(q.key));
```

This above code returns an error message:

> TS2345: Argument of type 'string | number | string[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => unknown'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '(value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => unknown'.

Is there a fix or another way I can filter the questionSet?

Comment: Can you show us what `createInput` is?